# How am I supposed to query for a persisted object's property's subproperty in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, properties, criteria, icriteria

I'm feeling dumb.

```
public class Uber
{
   public Foo Foo { get; set; }
   public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

...

var ubercharged = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Uber))
.Add(Expression.Eq("Foo.Name", "somename"))
.UniqueResult<Uber>();
return ubercharged;
```

This throws a "could not resolve property" error.

What am I doing wrong? I want to query for an Uber object that has a property Foo which has a Name of "somename".

updated with real life example, repository call, using fluent nhibernate:

```
    public UserPersonalization GetUserPersonalization(string username)
    {
        ISession session = _sessionSource.GetSession();

        var personuser = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(UserPersonalization))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("User.Username", username))
            .UniqueResult<UserPersonalization>();
        return personuser;

    }
```

The classes/mappings:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsApproved { get; set; }

}

public class Person
{
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}

public class UserPersonalization
{
    public virtual int UserPersonalizationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserId).GeneratedBy.Guid().ColumnName("UserId");
        Map(x => x.Username);
        Map(x => x.PasswordHash);
        Map(x => x.PasswordSalt);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        Map(x => x.IsApproved);
        Map(x => x.IsLockedOut);
    }
}

public class UserPersonalizationMap : ClassMap<UserPersonalization>
{
    public UserPersonalizationMap()
    {
        WithTable("UserPersonalization");
        Id(x => x.UserPersonalizationId).ColumnName("UserPersonalizationId");
        References(x => x.Person).ColumnName("PersonId");
        References(x => x.User).ColumnName("UserId");
    }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.PersonId).ColumnName("PersonId");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.Company).ColumnName("CompanyId");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can use the mappings to save an uber object to the database... so the mappings should work?

Comment: Should yes. You have maps for both objects correct?

Comment: Yes I think so, so the above Criteria should work and is 'theoretically' correct?

Comment: Theoretically. There is another way to go about it though. I'll add an answer for that method.

Comment: Oh thank you, the nhibernate documentation is a bit thin in my opinion...

Comment: If the maps are correct, you should be able to sort using the "Foo.Name" syntax. I had thought that fetches should work that way as well. Ah, beaten to it by Stuart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ubercharged = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Uber))
        .CreateCriteria("Foo")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", "somename"))
            .UniqueResult<Uber>();
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the mappings don't work correctly. This went a bit further but it looks like the Id's aren't currently set for the foreign key elements...

Comment: Had to specify the mappings more precisely... 

thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Can you sort using "ubercharged.AddOrder(Order.asc("Foo.Name")) syntax? This syntax should work in NHib 2.01. If not, your maps are not working correctly.

Stuart's answer should work fine for you though.